# Connect to Elastic Cloud from the Java Client

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I've been trying to connect to my ES instance on the Elastic cloud with no success using the Java client and following the [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/8.5/_basic_authentication.html)
In the hostname I put https://myinstance-xx.europe-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io

```
private String hostName = "https://myinstance-xx.es.europe-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io";
private String username = "username";
private String password = "pass";
@Bean
public ElasticsearchClient client() {
    final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
            new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(hostName, 9200))
            .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder ->
                    httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
    // Create the low-level client
    RestClient restClient = builder.build();
    // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
    ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
    // And create the API client
    return new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
}
```

However, I get an Connection Refused exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

What's the best way to connect to ES on Elastic Cloud through the Java Client?

Comment: check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/8.5/_encrypted_communication.html as you are using https

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to cloud.elastic.go/home after your are logged in, find the "Manage this deployment" link. It should be something like `https://cloud.elastic.co/deployments/xxxxxxxx`
2. Under "Applications" you should have an "Elasticsearch" enpoint (click on "Copy endpoint")
3. On the API console create an API Key:

```
POST /_security/api_key 
{
  "name": "my_key_name",
  "expiration": "15d"
}
```

That's gonna give you something like:

```
{
  "id": "API_KEY_ID",
  "name": "my_key_name",
  "expiration": 1670471984009,
  "api_key": "API_KEY",
  "encoded": "XxxxxxxxXXXXXxxxxxxXXXXxxxxxXXXX=="
}
```

4. Now in your Java code:

   ```
   // endpoint you copied
   String hostname = "youdepname.es.us-west1.gcp.cloud.es.io";
   String apiKeyId = "API_KEY_ID";
   String apiKeySecret = "API_KEY";
   String apiKeyAuth =
        Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(
            (apiKeyId + ":" + apiKeySecret)
                .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));


   RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
        new HttpHost(hostname, 9243, "https"))
        .setRequestConfigCallback(
            new RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback() {
              @Override
              public RequestConfig.Builder customizeRequestConfig(
                  RequestConfig.Builder requestConfigBuilder) {
                return requestConfigBuilder
                    .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                    .setSocketTimeout(60000);
              }
            });


   Header[] defaultHeaders =
        new Header[]{new BasicHeader("Authorization",
            "ApiKey " + apiKeyAuth)};
   builder.setDefaultHeaders(defaultHeaders);

   RestClient restClient = builder.build();

   // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
   ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(
        restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

   // And create the API client
   ElasticsearchClient client = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
   ```

That should do it. There are other ways to connect, but this is my preferred way.